# Monitor goes to sleep immediately after reboot

Tags: beagleboard

After booting my BeagleBord (Original Rev C5), Monitor shows the ubuntu login screen and everything seems fine. but after few seconds the monitor goes blank and displays "Going to sleep".
Why does this happen? and how can I prevent this?

Note: I am using a VGA cable and a HDMI/VGA converter to connect Monitor with the Board

Comment: Are you sure the board doesn't shut down or enter some power-saving mode? Are the power rails ok just before the monitor goes to sleep?

Comment: The board doesn't shut down, but I am not sure about the power-saving thing.
Power seems to be the same as nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It turned out that the HDMI/VGA converter drains much power from the circuit, So the Board shuts the HDMI interface after few seconds.
You should use a display with HDMI interface directly with Board (No Converter).